# Using NOW in a where clause

Tags: sql, date, where-clause

I have the below Where clause that I need to insert a NOW clause so everyday I run the search it updates to the correct dates. Could anyone assist me please?

```
( (status = 'APPROVED' or status = 'RDESPATCH' or status = 'INPRG' or status = 'DESPATCHED' or status = 'ONHOLD' or status = 'WAITAPPROVE') 
  and (woclass = 'WORKORDER' or woclass = 'ACTIVITY') 
  and targstartdate <= to_timestamp ('2020-09-24 00:00:00.000' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
  and historyflag = 0 
  and istask = 0 
  and siteid = 'CVL' 
  and fnlconstraint <= to_timestamp ('2020-09-24 00:00:00.000' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'))
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. Just like here.)

Comment: Unrelated, but: `status = 'APPROVED' or status = 'RDESPATCH' or status ...` can be simplified to `status in ('APPROVED', 'RDESPATCH', 'INPRG', ...)`

Comment: I'm using an IBM system called Maximo, the Where clause comes from the search I carried out but I want it to generate a report every morning so I don't have to go and run the search query myself.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- `IN` simplifies your code.
- Your code looks like Oracle.  You should be able to use `current_date`

So:

```
status in ('APPROVED', 'RDESPATCH', 'INPRG', 'DESPATCHED', 'ONHOLD', 'WAITAPPROVE') and 
woclass in ('WORKORDER', 'ACTIVITY') and
targstartdate <= current_date and
historyflag = 0 and
istask = 0 and
siteid = 'CVL' and
fnlconstraint <= current_date
```

Actually `current_date` is standard SQL and supported in most databases.

Comment: Can't wait for Sql Server to add current_date. Sure, work-arounds are easy enough, but we shouldn't have to.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn . . . Which is odd, because it has `current_timestamp`.

Comment: Oooh...  I just noticed you passed 1M. Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to filter against the current date. Most databases support `current_date` - Oracle (which your code looks like), Postgres, MySQL.

```
status IN ('APPROVED', 'RDESPATCH', 'INPRG', 'DESPATCHED', 'ONHOLD', 'WAITAPPROVE')
and woclass IN ('WORKORDER', 'ACTIVITY') 
and targstartdate <= current_date
and historyflag = 0 
and istask = 0 
and siteid = 'CVL' 
and fnlconstraint <= current_date
```